# How to prevent client get processes info of server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, security, iis

In C# , there is a method which can get the processes info on current machine as below:

```
Process[] myprocess = Process.GetProcesses();
```

But now I am working on how to prevent using this method on client side, if this method being invoked, the server will return "no permission".

This problem is due to the concern of webshell protection. yes, I can ban the upload or provide a series of identity authentication,etc, but I am considering even all the security lines being passed, the codes still cannot work.

Comment: If you mean "browser" when you say "client side", the browser cannot run code on the server and the server cannot run code on the client. Only JavaScript can run in the browser on the client, and it can't know anything about the server.

Comment: The group policy credentials should be setup to block unwanted access.

Comment: My guess is he wants to prevent that code to run when there is a http context (client call). But it should run if its a server thread invoking it. So the solution would be to check if a HttpContext exists, and deny the request if so.

Comment: @Wolf5: that's quite a stretch of the imagination.

Comment: It's the only way I can make that question seem logical, or the poster has little knowledge on server vs client side code here. So I'd say not much of a stretch. How would you interpret this?

Comment: @Wolf5: that the OP doesn't understand client vs. server, which is why I asked what was meant.

Comment: Probably. But my explanation would be valid if he has and Asp.Net app with a common library used for both client requests and internal requests (background thread) which has that one method returning a list of processes. By distinguishing a client context from a server context will solve it.